# In how many ways can we arrange 199 students in the first row of a lecture hall with 20 seats (Lecture hall has 201 seats)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

199 students are attending a lecture in a lecture hall with 201 seats. The first row has 20 seats. In how many was can we arrange the students in the first row if the order matters.

What I did was:

we can see the 2 empty seats as identical students. So all possible arrangements are :
$$\frac{201!}{2!\cdot181!}$$

But I think my answer is wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is not clear.  What difference does it make how many seats the first row has?

Comment: Im sorry edited my qestion

Comment: Still not clear.  Must we populate all $20$ seats in the first row? We know that there will be exactly $2$ empty seats in the hall.  Might either or both of those be in the first row?  If so, you have to handle each case ($0,1,2$ empty seats in the first row) separately and add.

Comment: they ask for all possible arrangements. So no empty seats, 1 and 2

Comment: Well there you go.  So, what's the answer if there are $0$ empty seats?

Comment: 201P20. The same if there is 1 empty seat.

Comment: Well...you pick $20$ students from $199$ and then you order them.  So $20!\times \binom {199}{20}$.  That's not the same as what you wrote.

Comment: what about the empty seats are they included

Comment: I was solving the case with $0$ empty seats.  Now, having done that, you should try to solve the case with exactly $1$ empty seat.  In the end, you need to get a sum of three terms.

Comment: so for no empty seats we have : 199P20 for one empty seat it is 200P20 and for two empty Seats (201P20)/2

Comment: You are just guessing.  Don't do that.  If you have one empty seat, then you know you have selected the "empty" student.  That can't be part of your choice any longer.  So you need to pick which seat is empty, and then you need to populate $19$ seats with students.

Comment: I don't know man. This question is driving me crazy the whole day

Comment: I told you the exact set of steps to follow to do the exactly $1$ empty seat case.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it all in terms of *choose* and *permute* functions,

*No empty seat first row:* $\Large^{199}C_{20}\cdot^{20}P_{20}$

*One empty seat first row:* $\Large ^{199}C_{19}\cdot^{20}P{19}$

*Two empty seats first row:* $\Large ^{199}C_{18}\cdot^{20}P_{18}$

Do you see a *pattern* ?  Add up all three for total ways of seating